# How to set rotation of an object on a specific axis?

Tags: python, game-engine

I am currently using the following to rotate my object:

```
eul = mathutils.Euler((math.radians(10), math.radians(10), math.radians(10)), "XYZ")
own.localOrientation = eul.to_matrix()
```

This seems to work just fine; it rotates the object by 10 on x, y, and z. However, I am only looking to set rotation on y and z. I have tried `eul.order` and other various ideas, but none have come upon success. How can I rotate an object with a specific set of axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean 10° around Y and 10° around Z?

```
mathutils.Euler((0, math.radians(10), math.radians(10)), "XYZ")
```

or do you mean 10° around X?

```
mathutils.Euler((math.radians(10), 0, 0), "XYZ")
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the rotation for y and z (second one) will change to 0? I am trying to leave those as they are. In other words, *only* set for the specified axis.

Comment: Each coordinate describes the angle around the according axis. That is why I asked what you want to get (some people say rotation in YZ plane which is rotation around Y-axis). So I'm not sure what you ask for. It seems that your answer is already there: mathutils.Euler((angleAroundX, angleAroundY, angleAroundZ), "XYZ")

Comment: I was trying to only do y and z, not x. I thought that, with that code, it would change x too?

Comment: The code "sets" the polar coordinates. As it expresses the difference to (0,0,0) you can interpret it as "change" from there. If you do not want a change you keep the coordinate at 0. - I have the impression you need something different.